# GROK Pattern for following log

Tags: logging, timestamp, logstash-grok

I'm having difficulty coming up with a pattern for the following log entry.

```
[INFO ] 2020-02-07 16:11:56.148 [localhost-startStop-1] DOMUtilities - System property DocumentBuilderCacheBlockSize is not defined, using default 25
```

The following is what I have.

```
  %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{YEAR} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}[%{DATA:threadName}\]\s+\%{DATA:javafile}\s[-:]\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Can anyone fill me in on what I am doing wrong please? I know the issue lies around the date format but I just cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grok-pattern has multiple issues (order is based on occurrence in grok pattern):

- The log-level is inside square brackets. The LOGLEVEL-pattern does not include any characters besides the defined words. Also, there is a whitespace after the loglevel and before the closing square bracket
- Your the date-values of your timestamp (year, month, day) are separated by hyphens which you haven't specified at all.
- The MONTH-pattern is for the full and/or abbreviated month **names**, e.g. *Feb* or *February*, Instead you need to use the MONTHNUM2-pattern which uses numbers.
- There is whitespace between the seconds and the thread-name
- You need to escape the opening square bracket at `[%{DATA:threadName}\]` since its a special character in regex
- There is no need for a backslash before `%{DATA:javafile}`

Please take a more detailed look at the [logstash grok-patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) and their definitions.

With the example log you've provided I came up with the following pattern:

`^\[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s?+\]\s+%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM2}-%{MONTHDAY}\s+%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}\s+\[%{DATA:threadName}\]\s+%{DATA:javafile}\s[-:]\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}`

You can verify your patterns on [this page](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result).

I hope I could help you.

Comment: This is great and points noted about how I can go about it in future. Thanks a lot. It works perfectly but doesn't work here https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ which is very strange. Working fine in my logstash.conf though so that's all that matters!